# cpp vs c++ compiler?

Tags: compiling, c++

What is the difference between the "cpp" and "c++" compilers in Ubuntu?

I've been attempting to clarify the various compiler synonyms used in Ubuntu (and Linux distros in general) before deciding which are the most elegant to use. Following symlinks with the "file" command quickly shows that "cc" links to "gcc" and that "c++" links to "g++".

"cpp" and "c++", however, are not symlinked but link to two different ELF files, which "cmp" shows to be dissimilar so they are not hard-linked either. Does anybody know the significance of this difference between these compilers?

Comment: `cpp` is a pre-processor, not a compiler - see `man cpp`

Answer (score 7):

@steeldriver: thanks, I'd just got around to figuring that myself. "cpp" is the Gnu pre-processor. It outputs pre-processed source-code.

I'd been confused by `cpp --help` producing exactly the same text as `c++ --help` — indicating that cpp was a full compiler, but it's not. Also I'd thought that the Gnu pre-processor was "gpp".

It turns out that "cpp" is the Gnu pre-processor — and "gpp" stands for *general-purpose* pre-processor, which seems to be something rather different.